# Change UDP payload NFQUEUE like feature on MacOS

Tags: network

I'd like to catch some UDP datagrams and change its payload a bit. On Linux there is NFQUEUE feature to pass matching packets to userspace program and modify it in any way. Is there something like NFQUEUE feature on MacOS?